# Maven compiler : difference between Xlint and showWarnings

Tags: maven, javac, maven-compiler-plugin

[According to documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#showWarnings), I can configure `maven-compiler-plugin` to show warnings using the `<showWarnings>` tag :

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.0</version>
  <configuration>
    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I can also configure the plugin to pass arguments to javac, in particular `-Xlint:all` which ["enables all recommended warnings"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html#options) :

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.0</version>
  <configuration>
    <compilerArgs>
      <arg>-Xlint:all</arg>
    </compilerArgs>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Are these two options strictly equivalent ? If not, what is the difference ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `compilerArgs` controls the behaviour of the java compiler. These settings are passed on to the compiler, and not used directly by the maven-compiler-plugin. Using `Xlint` you can control which warnings the java compiler outputs from the compilation process. You can also add e.g. `-Werror` to abort compilation upon warnings (which in general is a good practice).

The `showWarnings` configuration on the other hand, is a setting for the maven-compiler-plugin (not passed on to the java compiler). It controls whether the plugin will output the warnings generated by the java compiler. So if you set it to false (I really don't understand why that is the default), you won't see the warnings generated by the java compiler. Even worse, the build will *not fail* even if you have set `-Werror` in the compilerArgs.

Comment: Do you meant that when I configure -Xlint:all and showWarnings=false, maven won't output any compiler warning ?

Comment: Yes, I verified that with a test project. It will mute the warnings (at least those generated from my test code). Also if you set `-Werror` the build will succeed even if the compiler generates a warning.